# All goroutines asleep when executing goroutine anyways

Tags: go, udp, goroutine

I'm receiving the following error and I don't understand why:

`Send: Query Herefatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

You can see im calling a function `routine` i created using goroutine. I really dont have any more details to provide.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "sync"
)

const (
    udphost       = "127.0.0.1"
    udpport       = ":150"
    StopCharacter = "\r\n\r\n"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func routine() {
    defer wg.Done()
    // establish connection address parts
    schemaUri := udphost + udpport
    udpAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", schemaUri)

    // make connection
    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", nil, udpAddr)
    fmt.Printf("%v", conn)

    // defer close
    defer conn.Close()

    // handle connection errors
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Erorr Establishing UDP Connection")
        return
    }

    // input query
    message := "Query Here"

    // Write query to server
    conn.Write([]byte(message))
    conn.Write([]byte(StopCharacter))
    fmt.Printf("Send: %s", message)

    // Read response from server
    buffr := make([]byte, 1024)
    buffw := make([]byte, 1024)
    n, _, _, _, _ := conn.ReadMsgUDP(buffr, buffw)

    fmt.Printf("Receive: %s", n)

    // parse message
    msg := string(buffr[0:n])
    fmt.Println(msg)
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(1) 
    go routine()
    wg.Wait() 
}
```

Comment: If you run above code using simple print message there is no error https://play.golang.org/p/ZEQDjYFdWgp in using go routine. Are you running only single go routine as mentioned or there are others too

Comment: Im extremely new can you provide an answer with possibly whats going wrong?

Comment: I have added a link to code to regenerate an error but there is not as such when you are running your go routine. Run the code in my comment link

Comment: @jkushner: first, don't ignore errors. If your goroutines are blocked, the stack trace will show you where.

Comment: @JimB im getting an error here: `n, _, _, _, _ := conn.ReadMsgUDP(buffr, buffw)
` I did notice that my port wasnt correct so there was no server interaction, unfortunately though i cannot get serve interaction until tomorrow. Do you think the issue was not having server communication?

Comment: @jkushner: well, you can't read a message if there is no message (and BTW, you probably don't need `ReadMsgUDP`, use `Read`, or `ReadFrom*`). Either way, this code provided can't produce a deadlock, and the stack trace from your original error will provide you with the exact points that are blocking.

Comment: If you are not getting any answer when trying to read in this line `n, _, _, _, _ := conn.ReadMsgUDP(buffr, buffw)`, it will block indefinitely. Then `routine` is asleep and so is `main` because it is waiting in `wg.Wait()`. Then all routines are asleep.

Comment: @TehSphinX: blocked reading on a network connection does _not_ put the goroutine into a sleep state, and cannot cause the aforementioned fatal error. Otherwise network code would crash like this all the time, since most of your time is usually spent waiting on reads.

Comment: @JimB then why is it failing on `ReadMsgUDP` specifically with the only issue i see is no connection established

Comment: @jkushner: I don't understand. `ReadMsgUDP` is likely to fail, because you're using a "connected" UDP socket, so the first write gets an ICMP failure back, then the read call returns that response as an error (which you're ignoring here). If you remove the first Write call, or use a normal udp socket, Read will block indefinitely. None of this is really related to a deadlock.

Answer (score -5):

Try

```
func main(){
 var wg &sync.WaitGroup
 wg.Add(1)
 go routine(wg)
 ...
 wg.Wait()
}
func routine(wg *sync.WaitGroup){
 ...
 defer wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: i dont see anything going on here that hasnt been done